# why nio java use pipe instead of wait/notify to communication in multi thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, pipe, mutex, nio

selector use pipe to **wakeup** other blocking threads which execute select() method under Linux.

why don't use wait/notify or conditon.await/signal() to communication with threads??

Comment: Because `wait()` and `notify()` don't wake up selectors, of course.

Comment: dammit I misunderstood that question completely. removing my answer. thx EJP.